# Alternatives to using an asynchronous method in .net 4.0

Tags: .net, multithreading, c#-4.0, asynchronous

I am writing a WCF service which has to implement multi threading to call another 3rd party service.

I am using LINQ to create a "List" and send the list of objects to the client.

The "MyObject" has 5 properties:

- 3 statically stored in a table
- 2 dynamically calculated by the 3rd party service.

I am required to spawn thread(s) to read the 2 dynamic properties, with a timeout of 30 seconds. Example:

If there are 6 objects in the list,

- I should spawn 6 threads that execute asynchronously in parallel that call the 3rd party service for their each of their 2 properties.
- If I get all the results within 30 seconds, I send the 6 objects with all the properties to the client.
- If I do not receive the properties for any of the objects within 30 seconds, I have to set it to NULL for that object and return the list of objects to the client.

My code looks like this:

```
List<Dials> lstDial = new List<Dials>();
foreach(var c in dialsToShow)
{
    int threadId;
    AsyncMethodCaller caller =
        new AsyncMethodCaller(MyMethodThatCalls3rdPartyService);

    IAsyncResult result = caller.BeginInvoke(userName, out threadId, null, null);

    while (!result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(30000, false))
         avgBI = caller.EndInvoke(out threadId, result);

    property4 = avgBI[0];
    property5= avgBI[1]; 

    var dashboardObj = _repository.FindQueryable<DashboardDial_Tbl>()
                   .Select(p => new DialDetails()
                   {
                       Id = p.DialId,
                       Name= p.DialName,
                       Type = p.DialType,
                       IndividualStat = property4,
                       GroupStat = proprty5         
                    }).SingleOrDefault();
      dials.Add(dashboardObj); 
}
reponse.dialsList = dials;
```

The method that calls the 3rd party service has a delegate.It looks like this:

```
public delegate List<string> AsyncMethodCaller(
    string methodName, out int threadId);

private List<string> MyMethodThatCalls3rdPartyService(
    string userName, out int threadId)
{
    //Call the service
}
```

Can someone please help me achieve this using multi threading another way? I am using .Net 4.0 and VS2012.

Comment: Have a look at the task library, much more simple

Comment: Can you help me with some psuedo code for this?

Comment: I am going to rephrase your question as this is not specifically about WCF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`Parallel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.aspx) to run concurrent tasks in parallel:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    var input = new[] {2, 3, 4};

    var results = new ConcurrentBag<string>();

    Parallel.ForEach(input, value =>
        {
            value += 10;
            results.Add(value.ToString());
        });

    foreach (var result in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

To do a timeout you would have to do something inside the anonymous method or use a [`CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.cancellationtoken.aspx).

Or you could use the [`Task`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx) object itself:

```
public void DoStuff()
{
    int input = 2;

    Task<string> task = Task<string>.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var output = (input + 10).ToString();
            return output;
        });

    //use this if you want to wait for all your tasks to complete
    Task.WaitAll(task);

    //Calling result will implicitly cause a wait if the task is not complete
    Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
}
```

To timeout a task you can call [`Wait`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606.aspx) with a timeout on all the tasks individually or specify a timeout on the [`WaitAll`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235688.aspx) or you can use the CancellationToken again.

```
Task.WaitAll(new[] {task}, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

*EDIT*

I have tried to give you an implementation for your example although there are some bits that need clarification and there are parts of the example that don't tie up so I have had to make some assumptions:

1. Dials = DialDetails
2. lstDial = dials
3. "If I do not receive the properties for any of the objects within 30 seconds,I have to set it to NULL for that object" means that you still want the rest of the items, just not that one.

I have done it using a mixture of parallel foreach and task.

```
var dials = new List<DialDetails>();
Parallel.ForEach(dialsToShow, c =>
    {
        var task = Task<IList<string>>.Factory.StartNew(
            () => MyMethodThatCalls3rdPartyService(userName));
        // Get the item from the database while calling the service
        // However there appears to be no search going on here
        // the same type will always come back right?
        var dashboardObj = _repository.FindQueryable<DashboardDial_Tbl>()
                    .Select(p => new DialDetails()
                    {
                        Id = p.DialId,
                        Name= p.DialName,
                        Type = p.DialType      
                    }).SingleOrDefault();

        //Wait until the timeout
        task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));

        //If it did not timeout or no other error occurred us the results
        if (dashboardObj != null && task.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        {
            //Need to do some checking here for indexes
            dashboardObj.IndividualStat = task.Result[0];
            dashboardObj.GroupStat = task.Result[1];
            dials.Add(dashboardObj);
        }
    });
reponse.dialsList = dials;

private IList<string> MyMethodThatCalls3rdPartyService(string userName)
{
    //Call the service
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the code.One more question,though.Will the "IndividualStat" and "GroupStat" properties be assigned to the right dashboardobj?Will the properties(and the object to which it has to be assinged) in sync?

Comment: Regarding your assumption #3: Yes. If the 3rd party service is down/does not respond within 30 secs.,I will send the "dial" object with only the other properties(Id,Name,Type) and set the "IndividualStat" and "GroupStat" to string.empty.

Comment: @user1550951 Yes the results from the task will be assigned to the correct DialDetails although your example code to get the DashboardDial_Tbl from the repository appears to always return the same object which does not seem right. I would suggest that you play with the code in a simple project without the complications of the rest of your solution so that you understand what the code is doing.